# Cannot implicitly convert type "int" into Bool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console-application

```
            int ValueOne, ValueTwo, Numchar, Total;
        Console.WriteLine("This Is A Program For doing any Of the four mathematical Proccesses");
        Console.WriteLine("You can Add , substract , Divide And Multiply");
        Console.WriteLine("When Asked Please Type The Values Or The Proccesses You Want.");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type The First Value");
        ValueOne = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type The Second Value");
        ValueTwo = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Number Of The Proccess/Character You Want Meaning That (1 = +) , (2 = -) , (3 = *) , (4 = /)");
        Numchar = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));
        if ((Numchar) = 1)
            Total = ValueOne + ValueTwo;
        if ((Numchar) = 2)
            Total = ValueOne + ValueTwo;
        if ((Numchar) = 3
            Total = ValueOne * ValueTwo;
                if ((Numchar) = 4
                    Total = ValueOne / ValueTwo;
```

This is a console application using c# ,
What Gives me The Error is :
"If ((NumChar) = (number)"
I'm a beginner in visual studio and I just started taking the courses

Comment: Use `==` to compare values.  `=` is for assignment only.

Comment: `=` is assignment, you want to use `==`

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate.

Comment: and also for third and fourth condition you miss close bracket

Comment: You should ask a new question.  I am rolling back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((Numchar) = 1)
```

should be

```
if (Numchar == 1)
```

= is for assigning a value

== is for comparing values

EDIT: And as the comments point out, you missed the closing parentheses in your 3rd and 4th if statements

```
if ((Numchar) = 3
```

should be

```
if (Numchar = 3)
```

and drop the parentheses around Numchar, they are pointless

Answer (score 0):

use == to compare. for example:

```
if ((Numchar) == 2)
    Total = ValueOne + ValueTwo;
```

When you use a single equal, you are assigning a value to Numchar, and that new value gets returned (in this case an *int*)

Looks like you might be used to VB (based on your variable names, etc). Telerik has a nice VB to C# code converter you can use to double-check your results, here:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a value, not comparing it. Use `==` for comparison